# animat text inside html div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

How do i make the text ("try again") inside the div move back and forth?
when the player lose and the smily shows up i defined the text in the arrow will change to
"try again" and i want the player will have to click him in order to play again.

here is the fiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/41/

```
 $(".way").bind('mouseenter', function() {
      $('#highlight_lose').fadeIn(1000);
      $('.wall').css("background", '#fff');
        $(".white").html("Try again");
  /* this is what i tried */       $(".white").animate({
            "left": "-10px" }, 500);    
    })
```

Comment: Do you need only a jQuery based solution or is CSS animation OK? (Note: CSS animation is not supported by old IE browsers).

Comment: @Harry looking for only jquery solution:) thanks.

Comment: Ok, but is [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/uqcLn/46/) equivalent to what you are trying? This is CSS based, but if it is correct then I can try converting it to jQuery.

Comment: @Harry thanks for your will to help, as u said cssanimation not supported old browsers and my project is in jquery, i'v found what i need in the answer below of Baszz u can check it out if u interested, thanks again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make your animation work you might want to give a position:absolute to the .white element. After that, you can place the animation logic in some kind of loop (or interval) to move back and forth. Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/47/

```
var directions = ["-=10px", "+=10px"];
function move(i){
     $(".white").animate({ "left": directions[i] }, 300, function(){
         move((i ===0)? 1 : 0);
     });
 }

 move(0);
```

Comment: this is great can i animate the text inside the div only?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just wrap the text in a span or something, select that with jQuery and do the animation on that object.

Comment: i didn't succeed to wrap select and make it work , can u help me once again?

Comment: Add a <span> stag around the text and change your jQuery selector to $('.white span'). Remove the position:absolute from the .white element and make it position:relative. Add the position:absolute and a display:block to the new span element. This should do it.

Comment: here i did everything like u said and still not working: http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/48/

Comment: That is because you where removing the span when you where setting the html text. Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/49/

Comment: oopsi... umm but now it only work when the page loads i need it to work every time, sorry for the troubles